# Optimal to lookup and display column/row names from a table of binary data

Tags: excel, indexing, lookup

```
Job Coach   ConsumerName    Monthly General Goals   
Anna    Joe                 0          0    0
Sam     John                0          0    0
Veron   Jane                0          0    0
Bill    Jack                1          1    1
Anna    Jill                1          1    1
        Jim                 0          0    0
Bill    Jiang               1          1    1
        Jolly               0          1    1
Sam     Jiant               0          0    0
        Jap                 0          1    1
        Joule               1          1    1
        Aardvark            0          1    0
Drake   Darding             0          0    0
```

Hello, as you can see above I have two columns of strings; one column is "job coach" the other is "consumer name". There are three columns of 1's and 0's; monthly, general, and goals.

I'm trying to find the specific pattern of 1's and 0's in each of the rows, and to report it. For instance, the data says:

```
Consumer Jolly still has a a monthly which needs to be completed;
Consumer Aardvark still has a monthly which needs to be completed;
Consumer Aardvark still has a monthly and a goals which needs to be completed.
```

Lookup doesn't really work, because it only will return the first instance of the corresponding variable and not additionally instances.

I've tried a index function like this:

```
{=INDEX($C$2:$E$14,SMALL(IF($C$2:$C$14=0,ROW($C$2:$C$14)),ROW(1:1)),3)}
```

But that only would look up for a single column at a time, which makes the report rather cumbersome. I'm open to doing a loop in excel without formulas, however its not a simple looping formula, because I'm trying to look at each cell and to output the specific column name.

Any thoughts on how to best do it?

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear what the condition you want to check is, but if you want to check for a specific given pattern and return the customer name you can use this adjusted formula:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$14,SMALL(IF($C$2:$C$14&$D$2:$D$14&$E$2:$E$14="010",ROW($C$2:$C$14)-1),ROW(1:1)),1)
```

In your formula you checked only the first binary column and returned the last. You also had a mistake of returning the row number and not the index in the list which is `row-1` in your case.

So notice:

- The `INDEX` returns values from column `B`.
- The `IF` checks a pattern of `C&D&E` equals a pattern like `010` which can be changed or set to a reference.
- Then return the `ROW()-1` in case your list starts at row 2, to return the index in the data and not the actual row.